# How can I make IntelliJ IDEA report non-static methods that could be made static?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I make IntelliJ IDEA report non-static methods that could be made static? This was a default when I was using Resharper when developing in C#, I was hoping IDEA could do the same analysis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences - Editor - Inspections. Search for `"method may be 'static'"` (with the surrounding double quotes). Check the checkbox.